# Passing dynamic query parameters to an SQL query string in GeoPandas read_postgis() method

Tags: geopandas, psycopg2

Up to now, I used to query geospatial tables with [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/) and then convert the geometries to my needs using, e.g. [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Per the psycopg2 [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html), you **never** format your query string yourself. Instead, you let the [`.execute()`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) method of your cursor doing the actual job.

```
import psycopg2
sql_query = ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %(id)s;")

with psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
  with conn.cursor() as curs:
    curs.execute(sql_query, {'id': id})
    res = curs.fetchall()
```

Now, I'd like to use [`.read_postgis()`](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.read_postgis.html) of [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) to make an equivalent **clean and secure call** to my database.

But this method is a little bit skinny regarding the query string:

[image: GeoPandas' query string]

Is there a way to dynamically pass a dictionary of parameters to the call of GeoPandas ' [`.read_postgis()`](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.read_postgis.html) method? Maybe relying on the same mechanism that psycopg2 is using?

For the moment, my workaround is to take advantage from the psycopg2 way of doing by "[mogrifying](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify)" the execution:

[image: psycopg2 mogrify]

as such:

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_postgis(
        cursRemote.mogrify(sql_query, {'id': id}), # <- passing this guy instead of my raw query
        connector, geom_col='mygeometrycolumn'
    )
```

I would be glad to know if it exists a direct GeoPandas' way?

Comment: I use a SqlAlchemy (ORM) selectable, and pass arguments to the query with a dictionnary (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) and `read_sql` or `read_postgis` accept the SqlAlchemy selectable as query.